# Как с подгруженой библиотеки сделать вызов функции которая находится в файле подгрузки библиотеки?

Tags: c, lib

Извините за название вопроса, не чего лучше не придумал.
Вообщем есть файл main.c, в нём обявленно несколько функций, переменных и идёт подгрузка библиотеки, как-то так:

```
lib = dlopen(library, RTLD_LAZY);
fun = (void (*)(void))dlsym(lib, "run");
dlclose(lib);
```

Как мне можно с этой библиотеки вызвать функцию с файла main.c да и ещё передать переменную в параметрах тоже с файла main.c?

Comment: Передача указателя на функцию в либу как вариант. И указатель на переменную тоже можно передать из main.c

Comment: Мне б код, а то я новичок и неособо розбераюсь

Comment: Не имея представления о том, какую функцию и куда вы собираетесь передавать не выйдет вам рабочий код написать.
В приведенном вами примере уже есть получение указателя на функцию, в обратную сторону оно аналогично будет работать.

Comment: Ну вот например есть main.c и в нём в нём переменная "FCGX_Request request" и функция test которая принимает два параметра - void test(char *, FCGX_Request request) далее в функции main идёт подгрузка библиотеки "test.so и исполнение функции run(), а в этой функции нужно выполнить функцию test(" lalala", request);

Comment: Тойсть мне в подгружаемой библиотеки надо сделать так?
`bin = dlopen("main", RTLD_LAZY);
fun = (void (*)(void))dlsym(bin, "test");
dlclose(bin);`
Только я не понял как параметры передать и получить переменную.

Comment: Вам нужно передать указатель на test() в run(). И вызвать функцию по указателю внутри run(), dlopen для этого не нужен.

Comment: А как передать то указатель?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно решать эту задачу по разному (по крайней мере в Linux и др. *nix).

Если делать, как Вы изначально спрашивали, то  main надо собирать с ключем `-rdynamic`. При такой сборке линкер сделает динамическую таблицу внешних символов main аналогично той, что используется в .so библиотеках. Подробнее см. man gcc и man ld.

А о том, как передавать указатели (в т.ч. на фуннкции) (что Вам советовали в комментариях) написано в куче мест (и на этом сайте IMHO тоже не раз), но на всякий случай пример есть в коде.

В нем строится динамическая (.so) библиотека из функций `solib_func()` и `solib_callback_func()`, которые разными способами вызывают функцию `mainfunc()`, находящуюся в том же файле, что и `main()`. Передаваемый ей разными способами аргумент это глобальная переменная `e_text`, которая тоже определена в файле с `main()` (ее значение устанавливается в зависимости от аргументов `main()`).

```
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ more solib_func.c somain.c >/dev/tty
::::::::::::::
solib_func.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern char *e_text; // эта переменная из main

// gcc -fPIC -c solib_func.c
// gcc -shared -o libdyn.so solib_func.o

void
solib_func (char *a)
{
  printf(__FILE__": %s(%s)\n", __FUNCTION__, a);
  char **ptr_e_text = dlsym(0, "e_text");

  mainfunc(a);
  mainfunc(ptr_e_text ? *ptr_e_text : 0);
  mainfunc(e_text);
}

void
solib_callback_func (void (*f)(), char *a)
{
  printf(__FILE__": %s(%s)\n", __FUNCTION__, a);
  f(a);
  f(*(char **)dlsym(0, "e_text"));
  f(e_text);
}

::::::::::::::
somain.c
::::::::::::::
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

// gcc -o somain somain.c -ldl -rdynamic

char *e_text;

void
mainfunc (char *a)
{
  printf(__FILE__ ": %s(%s!)\n", __FUNCTION__, a);
}

static void 
fatal (const char *msg) 
{
  char *e = dlerror();
  printf("fatal %s: %s\n", msg, e);
  exit(1);
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  void *lib = dlopen("./libdyn.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (!lib)
    fatal("dlopen");

  long  (*hello)() = dlsym(lib,"solib_func");
  if (!hello)
    fatal("dlsym");
  hello(e_text = av[1] ? av[1] : "Hi, kohai");

  printf("using callback: f(mainfunc, %s)\n", e_text);
  if (hello = dlsym(lib, "solib_callback_func"))
    hello(mainfunc, e_text);
  else
    fatal("dlsym");

  dlclose(lib);
  return puts("End") == 0;
}
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ gcc -fPIC -c solib_func.c
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ gcc -shared -o libdyn.so solib_func.o
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ gcc -fPIC -o somain somain.c -ldl -rdynamic
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ ./somain 
solib_func.c: solib_func(Hi, kohai)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
using callback: f(mainfunc, Hi, kohai)
solib_func.c: solib_callback_func(Hi, kohai)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hi, kohai!)
End
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$
```

Обратите внимание, что функция в .so вызывает `dlsym(0, name)` для поиска внешнего имени в `main`.

Если что-то непонятно, спрашивайте.

Заметил Ваш комментарий

> Тойсть мне в подгружаемой библиотеки надо сделать так? bin =
>   dlopen("main", RTLD_LAZY); fun = (void (*)(void))dlsym(bin, "test");
>   dlclose(bin); Только я не понял как параметры передать и получить
>   переменную

Нет, так не пойдет. Если хотите динамически вызвать функцию в `main`, то можно добавить, например, в конец `solib_func()` код

```
  puts("using dlsym(\"mainfunc\")");
  void (*f)() = dlsym(0, "mainfunc");
  f(a);
```

и тогда получим

```
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ gcc -fPIC -c solib_func.c
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ gcc -shared -o libdyn.so solib_func.o
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$ ./somain Hello,\ student
solib_func.c: solib_func(Hello, student)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
using dlsym("mainfunc")
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
using callback: f(mainfunc, Hello, student)
solib_func.c: solib_callback_func(Hello, student)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
somain.c: mainfunc(Hello, student!)
End
avp@avp-ubu1:tst$
```

Comment: Спасибо, не сразу но все понял. А можно ли без -rdynamic как-то? А то основной код будет в библиотеке и не хотелось бы вызвать случайно функцию которая находится в основном исполняемой файле

Comment: @Виталий, я правильно понял, что Вы боитесь *одноименных функций* в main и .so? Действительно, в таком случае, использовать -rdynamic нельзя, будут вызываться функции из main. Остается только передавать в .so  адреса функций из main и аргументы (определенные в main) с которыми функция в .so  будет их вызывать. Т.е. это только вариант с вызовом `solib_callback_func` в somain.c и `f(a)` внутри solib_callback_func(). Вызов dlsym(0, name) внутри .so работать тоже не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, так и буду делать